# Javascript regulax expression - does not contain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Simple question, sorry.
What is the best way to test if string contains certain characters ?
For example I want to check if string contains '%' or '@' or '!'.

It should be something simple like:

```
/[^%@!]/gi.test("ban@na");
```

But I really need the best solution as fast as possible.
**Thank you very much!**

Comment: Both modifiers (`/gi`) are redundant in this case.

Comment: `/[%@!]/i.test("ban@na");` ?

Comment: Stefan, you can make this as an answer and I'll accept it.
Thank you very much!
Yes, the question was dumb enough.

Comment: raina77ow, thanks. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3):

This tests if a string contains '%' or '@' or '!'

```
function test(str) {
    return str.indexOf('%') >= 0 || str.indexOf('@') >= 0 || str.indexOf('!') >= 0
}
```

or

```
function test(str) {
    return /[%@!]/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if there are 12 characters that need to be tested?
I think it's more compact and better with regular expression?..

Comment: @JoeSmith, if there are 12 characters, then use a regex (the second snippet).